# Parallel zipping of a single large file

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, zip

Is there a way to do parallel zipping in Java?

I'm currently using `ParallelScatterZipCreator` but unfortunately it does parallel zipping per file. So if there's a single file that is much larger than other files, the parallel zipping only happens for smaller files. Then it has to wait until the large file is zipped serialy.

Is there a better library out there that utilizes all CPU cores even if we're zipping a single file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: You may not need compression at all. If you do, then you probably don't want to use the zip format, it's outdated tech with sizable downsides, and clearly you have some fairly specific needs. You probably want ZStandard (zstd).

### How does compression work

Compression works by looking at a blob of bytes and finding repetitions of some form within it. Thus, it is not possible to compress a single byte.

This makes the job **fundamentally at odds with parallelising**: If you take a blob of 1 million bytes and compress them by lopping that up into 10 chunks of 100k bytes each, compressing each miniblob individually, then any repetition such that one of the reptitions was in one miniblob and another was in another, means that you have missed an opportunity to compress data, that you would not have missed if you had compressed this data in one blob instead.

The only reason ZIP **does** let you parallellize a little bit, is because it is an old format - sensible at the time, but in this age, just about every part of the ZIP format is crap.

### Why is ZIP bad?

ZIP is a mixed bag, conflating two unrelated jobs.

1. A bundler. A bundling tool is some software that takes a bunch of files and turns that into a single stream (a single sack of bytes). To do so, the bundling tool will take the metadata about a file (its name, its owner/group or other access info, its last-modified time, etcetera), and the data within it, and serializes this into a single stream. zip does this, as does e.g. the posix `tar` tool.
2. A compressor. A compressor takes a stream of data and compresses it by finding repeated patterns.

zip in essence is only #1, but as part of the bundler, the part with 'the data within this file' has a flag to indicate that a compression algorithm has been applied to the bytes representing the data. In theory you can use just about any algorithm, but in practice, **every** zip file has **all** entries compressed with the DEFLATE algorithm, which is vastly inferior to more modern algorithms.

`.tar.gz` is the exact same technology (first bundle it: tar file, then gzip that tar file. gzip is the DEFLATE algorithm), but vastly more efficient in certain cases (it applies compression to the entire stream vs. restarting from scratch for every file. If you take a sack of 1000 small, similar files, then that in .tar.gz form is orders of magnitude smaller than that in .zip form).

Also, zip is old, and it made choices defensible at the time but silly in modern systems: You can't 'stream' zips (you can't meaningfully start unpacking one until the whole file has been received), because the bundler's info is at **the end** of the file.

### So why can I parallellize zips?

Because zips 'restart' their compression window on every file. This is inefficient and hurts the compression ratio of zip files.

You can apply the exact same principle to any block of data, if you want. Trade compression efficiency for paralellizability. ZIP is the format that doesn't do it in a useful way; as you said, if you have one much larger file, the point is moot.

'restart window at' is a principle that can be generalized, and various compression formats support it in a much more useful fashion (restart at every X bytes, vs. ZIPs unreliable 'restart at every file').

### What is the bottleneck?

Multiple aspects are involved when sending data: The speed at which the source provides the bytes you want to send, the speed at which the bytes are processed into a package that can then be sent (e.g. a zip tool, but can be anything, including just sending it verbatim, uncompressed), the speed at which the packaged-up bytes are transited to the target system, the speed at which the target can unpack it, and the speed at which the target can then process the unpacked result.

**Are you sure that the compression aspect is the bottleneck?**

In the base case where you read the bytes off of a harddisk, zip them up, send them across a residential internet pipe to another system, that system unzips, and saves them on a HDD, it is rather likely that the bottleneck is the network. Parallellizing the compression step is a complete waste and in fact **only slows things down** by reducing compression ratios.

If you're reading files off of a spinning platter, then the speed of the source is likely the bottleneck, and parallel processing **considerably slows things down**: You're now asking the read head to bounce around, and this is *much* slower than reading the data sequentially in one go.

If you have a fast source, and a fast pipe, then the bottleneck is doubtlessly the compression and uncompression, but the solution is then **not to compress at all**: If you are transferring data off of SSDs or from a USB3-connected byte-spewing sensor and transfer it across a 10M CAT6 cable from one gigabit ethernet port to another, then why compress at all? Just send those bytes. Compression isn't going to make it any faster, and as long as you don't saturate that 1Gb connection, you gain absolutely nothing whatsoever by attempting to compress it.

If you have a slow pipe, then the only way to make things faster is to compress as much as you can. Which most definitely involves not using the DEFLATE algorithm (e.g. don't use zip). Use another algorithm and configure it to get better compression rates, at the cost of CPU performance. Parallelising is irrelevant; it's not the bottleneck, so there is no point whatsoever in doing it.

### Conclusions

Most likely you want to either send your files over uncompressed, or ZStandard your files over, tweaking the compression v. speed ratio as needed. I'm not aware of any ZStandard (zstd) impl for java itself, but the [zstd-jni](https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni) project gives you a java-based API for invoking the C zstd library.

If you insist on sticking with ZIP, the answer is a fairly basic 'nope, you cannot really do that', though you could in theory write a parallel ZIP compressor that has worse compression power but parallelizes better (by restarting the window within a single file for larger files in addition to the forced-upon-you-by-the-format restart at every file), and produces ZIP files that are still compatible with just about every unzip tool on the planet. I'm not aware of one, I don't think one exists, and writing one yourself would be a decidedly non-trivial exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Indeed zip is no good but unfortunately our customers demand zip format. You're probably right that there's no zip library that can do that, but one can hope.

Comment: This answer is wrong on sooo many accounts.. including but not limited to: 1. “ the job fundamentally at odds with parallelising” - wrong at least for zip: with deflate referring back into the stream maximum for 32k - it is perfectly feasible to compress chunks with a 33k-overlap. 2. “ it is rather likely that the bottleneck is the network. Parallellizing the compression step is a complete waste and in fact only slows things down by reducing compression ratios.” - as wrong as it can possibly be. Whenever the bottleneck is network - compression will speed things up.

Comment: 3. “ probably don't want to use the zip format, it's outdated tech with sizable downsides, and clearly you have some fairly specific needs. ” - as it follows from the answer and from subsequent OP comment - these “special needs” require ZIP doormat, plain and simple. 4. “ Use another algorithm and configure it to get better compression rates, at the cost of CPU performance. Parallelising is irrelevant; it's not the bottleneck, so there is no point whatsoever in doing it.” - wrong again. This stands ONLY as long as due to lower speed, compression doesn’t become a bottleneck itself.

Comment: @No-BugsHare You have decided to knee jerk into a rather hateful takedown of this post. However, in your first comment, you completely miss the mark, and read a line in this answer in a bizarre fashion. I'm pretty sure it's you, and not due to being hard to understand. __Parallellizing__ the compression step is not useful if the bottleneck is the pipe. I'm not saying "If the pipe is the problem, do not compress". I'm saying: "If the pipe is the problem, do not compress _in parallel_, just compress as normal".

Comment: @rzwitserloot So you don't have objections against other 3 points I raised? Especially against the one about compression being "fundamentally at odds with parallelizing" - which is _fundamentally_ wrong? BTW, your definition of compression is also Badly Wrong (compression doesn't necessarily need to work on "blob of bytes") - and also, under certain circumstances (like "being a part of larger bit stream") it is perfectly possible to compress one single byte (hint - it is only LZ family which looks for repetitions, entropy coders don't).

Comment: @No-BugsHare I identified you evidently just want to score some internet points given the wildly misconstrued point about the pipe being the bottleneck. You're looking for a fight, I guess. I'm not interested.